# Calling a static method from a non-static context

Tags: java, android

i'm trying to call a few methods in the SCS class from the onReceive method in my broadcast receiver but it gives me error everywhere "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method CheckConnection() from the type SCS"

SCSReceiver.class

```
public class SCSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    SCS.mehtodName(context);
    // ... do what you need to do here...
}
```

SCS.class

```
public class SCS extends Activity {
private Handler handler;
private Runnable runnable;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_connection_stablizer);
}
public static void mehtodName(Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    CheckConnection();
}

private void CheckConnection() {
    ConnectivityManager cn = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo nf = cn.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (nf != null && nf.isConnected() == true) {
        //CheckAccess();
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Network Available! now checking Inernet access..",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        // Toast.makeText(this, "Network Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        // .show();
    }
}
```

manifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:name="com.xyz.netspeedmaster.SCS"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_connection_stablizer" >
    </activity>

     <receiver android:name="com.xyz.abc.SCSReceiver" >
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Have another look at the error message. it's not what it says in your title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `SCSReceiver` class an inner class of the `SCS` class:

```
public class SCS extends Activity {
private Handler handler;
private Runnable runnable;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_connection_stablizer);
}
public static void methodName(Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    CheckConnection();
}

private void CheckConnection() {
    ConnectivityManager cn = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo nf = cn.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (nf != null && nf.isConnected() == true) {
        CheckAccess();
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Network Available! now checking Inernet access..",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        // Toast.makeText(this, "Network Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        // .show();
    }
}

class SCSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    methodName(context);
    // ... do what you need to do here...
}

}
```

No need for `SCS.methodName`, just call the method directly.

Comment: Have you tried my solution ?

Comment: Ah that, you should delete it. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Did the solution work for you ?

Comment: Check my update: Don't use SCS.methodName(context). Call it directly : methodName(context)

Comment: I don't think you need to modify your manifest file. Leave it as is.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to invoke your BroadcastReceiver based on System Receivers, then you can try using Dynamic BroadcastReceiver through which you can invoke the methods of your Activity.

```
public class SCS extends Activity {
private Handler handler;
private Runnable runnable;
private IntentFilter filter;
private BroadcastReceiver receiver;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_connection_stablizer);

    filter=new IntentFilter("com.your_package.ANY_TEXT_STRING");
    receiver=new BroadcastReceiver(){

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                 mehtodName(context);  //Invoke your methods from here
                    }
           };
       registerReceiver(filter,receiver);

       //Place the below two lines where you want to trigger BroadcastReceiver
       Intent intent=new Intent("com.your_package.ANY_TEXT_STRING");
       sendBroadcast(intent);

}
public static void mehtodName(Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    CheckConnection();
}

private void CheckConnection() {
    ConnectivityManager cn = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo nf = cn.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (nf != null && nf.isConnected() == true) {
        //CheckAccess();
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Network Available! now checking Inernet access..",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        // Toast.makeText(this, "Network Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        // .show();
    }
}
```